# Customer must have at least 3 e-mails

Tags: mysql, database-design, constraints, data-modeling, data-integrity

I'd like to create a database model where every customer **must have at least 3** e-mails.

The first idea is to model it as follows (I will use MySQL syntax):

```
create table customer (
  id int not null auto_increment primary key,
  ...
  text e-mail1 not null,
  text e-mail2 not null,
  text e-mail3 not null);

create table customer_emails(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key, 
    text e-mail
    ...
    foreign key (customer_id) references customer(id));
```

You can notice that in this model there is a possibility for data redundancy.

Let's assume an example we want to insert a customer having 5 e-mails (e1, e2, e3, e4, e5) into the database.
Three e-mails (e1, e2, e3) will be certainly inserted into table `customer`.
Now, we have 2 possibilities.

1. insert e4, e5 to `customer_emails`
2. insert e1, e2, e3, e4, e5 to `customer_emails`

What is better approach and why? 1 (no redundancy) or 2 (with redundancy)?

Comment: Those aren't the things that can be reasonably implemented structurally, as you have probably noticed. Creating foreign key fields only to proof some 2nd order business rule is IMHO not a good idea. Such things are best controlled by triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option is better.  However in your case, all `customer` emails should be stored in `customer_emails` regardless of if they have 3 or 25.

If you have multiple emails that a customer can have, you should not store any of them in the `customer` table.  Instead store all of them in the `customer_emails` table. Get rid of the `e-mail1`, `e-mail2`, `e-mail3`.  It would be confusing to have to get three emails from the `customer` table and the rest from another table.

Image how you would get all of the emails for a particular customer in scenario 1:

```
SELECT c.id, c.email1, c.email2, c.email3, ce.email
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN customer_emails ce on ce.customer_id = c.id
WHERE id = 67
```

The above would return:

```
c.id  c.email1     c.email2     c.email3    ce.email  
67    ed@mm1.com   ed@mm2.com   ed@mm3.com  ed@mm4.com
67    ed@mm1.com   ed@mm2.com   ed@mm3.com  ed@mm5.com
67    ed@mm1.com   ed@mm2.com   ed@mm3.com  ed@mm6.com
67    ed@mm1.com   ed@mm2.com   ed@mm3.com  ed@mm7.com
67    ed@mm1.com   ed@mm2.com   ed@mm3.com  ed@mm8.com
67    ed@mm1.com   ed@mm2.com   ed@mm3.com  ed@mm9.com
```

Now think about this, scenario 2:

```
SELECT c.id, ce.email
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN customer_emails ce on ce.customer_id = c.id
WHERE id = 67
```

would return:

```
c.id  ce.email
67    ed@mm1.com
67    ed@mm2.com
67    ed@mm3.com
67    ed@mm4.com
67    ed@mm5.com
67    ed@mm6.com
67    ed@mm7.com
67    ed@mm8.com
67    ed@mm9.com
```

The second option is much easier/cleaner to deal with since all the email addresses are in one field.

Comment: If you store e-mails only in the `customer_emails` table, can you enforce that three of them will not be null by the `MySQL` DB, or is the only possibility to do it in `PHP` code?

Comment: You would have to do that in your PHP code.  Just curious, why would you force them to enter three email addresses?  Isn't 1 enough?  Anyway, it should be pretty easy to do on the front end.  Just provide 3 text boxes for the email addresses that have to be filled in before the record can be saved.

Comment: This is requirement (integrity constraint). I would like somehow define it in `MySQL` to check after inserting new customer that it has three e-mails.
It should not happen that I have in the DB customer record and for this record only 2 e-mails in customer_emails table.

Comment: what is your front end application?

Comment: front end will be PHP, though if later there are more front ends (which is quite probable) for modifying data, the integrity could be lost.

Comment: I think all around it is a bad design.  To force them to have at least 3 email addresses and then still allow them to enter more is out of the norm.  You could handle it with either of the two options you presented.  But, what are the email addresses for?  Do they represent something/someone that can be handled differently?

Comment: E-mail for customer is only an example for the question to be more understandable. I don't have full control over front ends (I'm doing only DB design and one front-end). Should I tell, this is not possible in MySQL?

Comment: The only way it is possible to force the three email addresses in MySQL is by using your first option.  Storing the first 3 3mail addresses in `customer` and the rest of them in `customer_emails`.  However, your queries will just be a little uglier and out of the norm.